# DATEDIFF in DataSet Query Builder

Tags: sql, dataset, query-builder

How do I use DATEDIFF in query builder? I am trying to calculate the age upon insertion.

I have this working insert code done in SqlQuery

```
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Employee]
           ([FirstName]
           ,[MiddleName]
           ,[LastName]
           ,[Age]
           ,[Gender]
           ,[Birthday]
           ,[PositionID]
           ,[Status]
           ,[ContactNumber]
           ,[Photo]
           ,[Password])
VALUES
           ('Lovenia'
           ,'Celestial'
           ,'Roman'
           ,(SELECT DATEDIFF(hour,'5-28-1998',GETDATE())/8766)
           ,'Male'
           ,'01-28-1998'
           ,'2'
           ,'Employed'
           ,'09128773636'
           ,null
           ,'somepassword')
GO
```

And then when I convert it to Query Builder, an error pops out and says no subqueries allowed

here is the code in QueryBuilder

```
    INSERT INTO Employee
                         (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, Gender, Birthday, PositionID, Status, ContactNumber, Photo, Password)
VALUES        (@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName, (Select DATEDIFF('hour',@Birthday, GETDATE()) / 8766),@Gender,@Birthday,@PositionID,@Status,@ContactNumber,@Photo,@Password)
```

I removed the select statement and left out just `DATEDIFF(hour,'5-28-1998',GETDATE())/8766`

But still gets an error

I read that `DATEDIFF()` isn't supported in Query builder, so are there any alternative way (similar to `DATEDIFF()`) to calculate the age?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nevermind, I figured it out**

The error was at `DATEDIFF()`'s parameter 1, i removed the qoutes and changed it to `hh`, also fixed the conversion from string to date :D

Here's the code

```
INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, Gender, Birthday, PositionID, Status, ContactNumber, Photo, Password)
VALUES        (@FirstName,@MiddleName,@LastName, DATEDIFF(hh, CONVERT(varchar(30),@Birthday, 102), GETDATE()) / 8766,@Gender,@Birthday,@PositionID,@Status,@ContactNumber,@Photo,@Password)
```